# Error in copy data ADF: FTP failed to get file length

Tags: ftp, azure-data-factory

While trying to build a pipeline that contains:
a getMetadata --> Filter --> ForEach --> Copy data

I have being facing the below error while trying to retrieve the source file:

> ErrorCode=FtpFailedToGetFileLength,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=FTP
> failed to get file length 'file_01/', file
> 'Filename_20201113_DATE_20211102_CODE01.DAT'
> Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The
> remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file
> not found, no access).,Source=System,'

Is there any explanation on why this error appears? How to fix it?

Comment: have you enabled `Sequential` in `ForEach` activity settings ?

Comment: I didnt enable sequential in the ForEach settings, should I do that ?

Comment: You can try to see if that has any effect, sometimes it is due to concurrency settings on ftp server side

Comment: Unfortunatly, it returns the same error even with with Sequential setting enabled.

Comment: Can you verify that the file actually exists at the path you indicated. If this is the folder `file_01/` you might want to try to escape the slash. Otherwise the copy activity will try to navigate to `file_01//Filename_20201113_DATE_20211102_CODE01.DAT`.